# Is there a schema registry specification?

Tags: java, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I have a simple question about schema registry in general. Is there a common specification for a schema registry? I mean if I switch from confluent to cloudera can I have a problem? Do they follow the same REST API? If so, who is responsible for define this specification and how can I see if a specific implementation is compatible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, I didn't find a common specification for schema registries but I found out the Cloudera Schema Registry (hortonworks schema registry) is compatible with confluent. I mean, there is a specific endpoint that provides some sort of compatibility. I performed a bunch of tests with a confluent client and it worked pretty well. In fact, even KafkaAvroSerdes worked without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Though there may always be caveats regarding super new versions or so, in general the Cloudera Schema Registry is designed so there should not be any problem to use this instead of the Confluent Schema Registry.

**Explicit disclosure: I am an employee of Cloudera.**